# What logs do I need to see to know httpd failure reason?

Tags: linux

My httpd fails unexpectedly after every reboot even I have enabled the service for bootup using **systemctl enable httpd**. Now I wana know the reason for its failure, but I don't know where to see which logs to check or what command to issue on centos 7.

Answer (score 2):

Check the error log details in /var/log/httpd/error.log

For access log details check in /var/log/httpd/access.log

Kindly enable the debug mode in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf for better recording of logs

Answer (score 1):

Start with the command:

```
systemctl status -l httpd
```

This will tell you if its active or not and when the last time the service manager tried to start it. It'll also give you a process try if its active and it will also give you the last logged messages related to the service.

However to get further logs of the server check /var/log/

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```